# Modify lifetime for url when change fe-password

Tags: url, passwords, typo3, lifetime

I wonder how you can change the lifetime of the url when fe-user requests to change his password.

Does anyone know where to find these option?

I already looked it up at the internet and also tried to search for it in the typo3 global conf. No success.

Thanks in advance and for your hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read in the [manual](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/felogin/6.2/Configuration/Index.html#forgetlinkhashvalidtime), there is a configuration called `forgetLinkHashValidTime` where you can set the lifetime in hours.

For example, if you want a lifetime of 1 hour, just place in your Setup the Typoscript:

```
plugin.tx_felogin_pi1.forgetLinkHashValidTime = 1
```

Edit: There seems to be a typo in the manual, as far as I know it should be `forgotLinkHashValidTime` you should also try

```
plugin.tx_felogin_pi1.forgotLinkHashValidTime = 1
```

Comment: Thanks.It was the right word to search for.
Adding in Typoscript didn't overwrite the value so I had to do it the old way changing it directly in file 'sysext/felogin/ext_typoscript_setup.txt'.